# Memory allocation using malloc for structures not working properly

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, malloc

```
struct student* addStudent(struct student* list, int* length){
    struct student* newList = malloc(sizeof(list)*(*length+1));
    for (int i=0; i<*length; i++){
        strcpy(newList[i].name, list[i].name);
        strcpy(newList[i].rollNumber, list[i].rollNumber);
        strcpy(newList[i].class, list[i].class);
    };

    //Adding some data in the added element

    free(list);
    (*length)++;
    return newList;
}

void main(){
    struct student* list = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    struct student** ptrToList = &list;
    strcpy(list[0].name, ""); 
    strcpy(list[0].rollNumber, ""); 
    strcpy(list[0].class, ""); 

    int length = 1;

    while (1){
        printOptions();
        int option;
        printf("Your pick: ");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        newLn();

        switch(option){

            case 1:
            *ptrToList = addStudent(*ptrToList, &length);
```

The problem I am having is that for the first time when the while loop runs, case 1 runs and I am able to add the data, and in the subsequent iterations as well I am able to access that data using *ptrToList, but whenever I try to run the case 1 again, the program ends. Why is it so?

Comment: `list` is a pointer, so when you do `sizeof(list)`, you are getting the size of a pointer rather than the size of the type being pointed to.

Comment: So I should change it to ```sizeof(struct student)```?

Comment: I would use `sizeof(*newList)`, but `sizeof(struct student)` should also work.

Comment: You've essentially recreated `realloc`. How about: `struct student * addStudent(struct student *list, int *length) {  list = realloc(list,sizeof(*list) * (*length + 1));  struct student *cur = &list[*length++];    return list; }`